# Vue.js Component doesn't appear when embedded in another component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a header, logo, menu, and menu item.

The menu item contains the text "This is a menu item", but vue is not processing and displaying it.

These are the components:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <mainHeader />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import mainHeader from './components/mainHeader.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    mainHeader
  }
}
</script> 

<style>

html,body{

box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}


#app{
background-color:gray;
}

</style>
```

./components/mainHeader.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="main-header">
        <logo />
        <mainMenu />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import logo from "./logo.vue";
import mainMenu from "./mainMenu.vue";

export default
{
    name: 'mainHeader',
    components:
    {
        logo,
        mainMenu,
    }
}
</script>
```

./components/mainMenu.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="main-menu">
        <menuItem />
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import menuItem from "./menuItem.vue";

export default
{
    name: "mainMenu",
    components:
    [
        menuItem
    ]
}
</script>
```

./components/menuItem.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="menu-item">
        This is a menu item
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default
{
    name: "menuItem"
}

</script>
```

When I check the DOM, the menuItem is not being parsed into a div with the message:

```
  <div id="app">
    <div data-v-ea6a1e94="" id="main-header">
      <div data-v-4b16403b="" data-v-ea6a1e94="" id="logo"></div>
      <div data-v-d2968a70="" data-v-ea6a1e94="" id="main-menu">
        <menuitem data-v-d2968a70=""></menuitem>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get the component to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components option has an object as a value :

```
 components:{
        menuItem
    }
```

it's recommended to name the component using kebab-case:

```
   name: "menu-item"
```

and the file name with CamelCase `MenuItem`

and import it like :

```
  import MenuItem from "./MenuItem.vue";
```

then register it like :

```
 components:{
        MenuItem
    }
```

finally use it like `<menu-item ... />`

Comment: Is there any situation where an array would be used? Why doesn't vue give an error or warning about it?

Comment: it should give you an error like the component is not registered

Comment: It gave no error in visual code or in vue. It simply showed an empty html element.

Comment: did you check the browser console?

Comment: Yea I see it in there now. I was in the vue devtools tab and expected any vue related information to be in there. Its my first hour using vue and I got stuck on the stupidest typo.